# Counting of word repetitions in a string

Tags: java, string, find, counting, cpu-word

The robot can move on the plane in 4 directions: U - up, D - down, L - left, R - right. Traffic example is UUDLR, DLRUD. I have to implement the "walk" method so that it returns the robot position after passing the indicated path. So I do this:

```
class Main {

static int[] walk(String path) {

int[] A = {0,0};
char charFromPath;

for (int i = 0 ; i < path.length() ; i++) {
      charFromPath = path.charAt(i);
      if(charFromPath == 'U')
      {                           
          A[1]++;
      }
      if(charFromPath == 'D')
      {                           
          A[1]--;
      }
      if(charFromPath == 'L')
      {                           
          A[0]--;
      }
      if(charFromPath == 'R')
      {                           
          A[0]++;
      }
  }
    return A;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        String path="UUDLR";
        int[] position = walk(path);

        System.out.println("case 1 - path "+path+ " position 0,1");
        if(position[0]==0 && position[1]==1)
            System.out.println("the robot went right");
      else
            System.out.println("the robot smashed");
    }

    {
        String path="DLRUD";
        int[] position = walk(path);

        System.out.println("\ncase 2 - path "+path+ " position 0,-1");
        if(position[0]==0 && position[1]==-1)
            System.out.println("the robot went right");
        else
            System.out.println("the robot smashed");
    }
}}
```

Now in **version 2** according to logic U, D, L, R, commands are UP DOWN LEFT RIGHT. Traffic example is UPUPLEFTRIGHTUP.

Now in **version 3** commands are for instance 3xUP 2xLEFT DOWN RIGHT. 3xUP means move three times up and 2xLEFT 2 times left. Add a restriction in movement for the robot, he cant go outside the 10x10 area (item 10.10 or -10, -10 is the last valid value).

I have no idea how to write it. How to count the number of repetitions string in string?

Comment: Check the answer, and tell me if you need more help and if it does answer your questions.

Comment: I do not understand very much :( . how can I do the function with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
String str = "UPUPLEFTRIGHTUP";
int countUP = ( str.split("UP", -1).length ) - 1;
int countLEFT = ( str.split("LEFT", -1).length ) - 1;
int countRIGHT = ( str.split("RIGHT", -1).length ) - 1;
int countDOWN = ( str.split("DOWN", -1).length ) - 1;
```

The restriction can be verified by comparing the `int` values to the limits of the box (`10*10` in your case).

For the position, if we suppose each movement is 1 unit then :

```
int x = 0; //starting point in Ox axis
int y = 0; //starting point in Oy axis 
x = countRIGHT - CountLeft;
y = countUP - CountDOWN;
```

The couple `(x,y)` is the position of your robot.

### move function :

```
int[] walk(String path) {
   int[] position = {0,0};
   int countUP = ( path.split("UP", -1).length ) - 1; //Counts how many UP command
   int countLEFT = ( path.split("LEFT", -1).length ) - 1; //Counts how many LEFT command
   int countRIGHT = ( path.split("RIGHT", -1).length ) - 1; //Counts how many RIGHT command
   int countDOWN = ( path.split("DOWN", -1).length ) - 1; //Counts how many DOWN command
   position[0] = countRIGHT - countLEFT;
   position[1] = countUP - countDown;
   return position;
}
```

Comment: I do not understand very much :( . how can I do the function with this?

Comment: For what version ? @141_MATRIX_141

Comment: for ver 2 if u have time but can u use function "walk"?

Comment: Edited my answer. you just call it like : `walk("UPUPLEFTRIGHTUP");` in your main function.

Comment: No problem :) @141_MATRIX_141 For the third version you should use regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

for version 2 you could split your original string and put it in an array with a method you can call on a string `String [] tmpsplit = tmp.split(" ");`. That way your array has inside each cell one direction (UP or DOWN or LEFT or RIGHT).

Then you can put this array in a similar for with the one that you have for version 1. Replace the `charFromPath == 'U'` with `tmpsplit[i].equals("UP")`

Comment: Could you write on because I dont think I understand it ;/